# Tile indices mismatched between layers in Godot 4 Isometric Tilemaps. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: godot, godot4

recently I started using Godot 4.2 to create a FF-Tactics like game. I am using an Isometric Tilemap 2D (Diamond right, vertical offset) with multiple layers. I intend to use them to encode the Z-Dimension. When I build my Layers though, one layer is offset (see the attached images, marking the tile with the green block).

In Ground_2 (Z-Index 2), the tile is (11,-9),
[image: Ground-2]
while the tile that should be below (by eye) is (10,-8) in Ground_1 (Z-Index 1).
[image: Ground-1]

This completely throws of my path-finding (Atsar3d) which just climbs the wall (it should not climb more than 1 block height).
[image: Path]

So far I have played around with Offset, Z-Axis, Reordering the Layers and a few other things, but so far nothing helped.

Thanks a lot for helping!

PS: I know my path markers (and also my mouse hovering) is ill positioned, still working on that just in case someone has hints.